# How is the this pointer captured?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, this

Consider the following code:

```
struct S
{
  int x;
  void f()
  {
    auto l = [&](){ x = 42; }; //this is implicitly captured here
  }
};
```

§5.1.2/14 states:

> An entity is captured by copy if it is implicitly captured and the capture-default is = or if it is explicitly captured with a capture that does not include an &.

Hence I conclude, that `this` is not *captured by copy*. But then by §5.1.2/15:

> An entity is captured by reference if it is implicitly or explicitly captured but not captured by copy. It is unspecified whether additional unnamed non-static data members are declared in the closure type for entities captured by reference.

`this` is *captured by reference*. But now §5.1.2/17 states:

> [...] If `this` is captured, each odr-use of `this` is transformed into an access to the corresponding unnamed data member of the closure type, [...]

As far as I understand, this implies that there must be an unnamed data member in the closure type corresponding to the `this` pointer. But since `this` is *captured by reference* the standard doesn't demand that such a member exists. What do I get wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The standard does a poor job of making it clear, but `this` can only be captured by copy. It could not possibly be captured by lvalue-reference since `this` is an rvalue per C++11 §9.3.2/1.

Note that the standard forbids explicitly capturing `this` by reference since (a) the grammar does not allow `&this` in a capture list since `this` is lexically a keyword and not an *identifier*, and (b) 5.1.2/8 forbids explicit capture of `this` when the capture-default is `=`.

It would seem to be an error in the specification that `this` can be implicitly captured when the capture-default is `&`, suggesting that it is captured by reference.

Comment: Where does it say that you can't capture an rvalue by reference?  It seems totally unspecified exactly what happens when something is captured by reference, at least in n3242 (what I have on hand).  In particular, 5.1.2/15 as quoted doesn't say that "an lvalue reference is declared in the closure type", instead it explicitly leaves this unspecified.

Comment: @rmcclellan Grammatically, you must refer to something by an identifier in order to capture it either explicitly or implicitly. There aren't a whole lot of names that designate rvalues in C++: `this` and `nullptr` come to mind. A quick glance at 2.12/1 turns up `true` & `false` as well. All are designated by keywords in the grammar. I suppose it's implicit that use as a keyword forbids them from matching the general *identifier* production in the grammar? Presumably that's why `this` is special-cased in the grammar production for *capture*.

Comment: [GCC 4.8.1 seems to concur with my suggestion that keywords are not identifiers](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c44c84564e7d04f3). There is simply a hole in the specification that suggests that `this` can be implicitly captured by reference, despite the fact that the grammar makes it impossible to capture it by reference explicitly.

Comment: In N3242 5.1.2/11, it does explicitly state that `this` can be implicitly captured, and combined with 5.1.2/15, it seems pretty clear that `this` can be captured by reference.  I agree with you that it doesn't make a lot of sense to capture `this` by reference and it is arguably an error.

Comment: A _keyword_ **is** an _identifier_ by §2.12/1. The use of _keywords_ like `true` or `nullptr` is ill-formed by §5.1.2/10: "The identifiers in a capture-list are looked up using the usual rules for unqualified name lookup (3.4.1); each such lookup shall find a variable with automatic storage duration declared in the reaching scope of the local lambda expression."

Comment: @MWid at the level of the grammar, the syntactic units are tokens: per 2.7 [lex.token] *keyword* and *identifier* are separate tokens. So when they appear in grammatical productions in the standard `nullptr` and `this` and `if` etc. represent *keyword* tokens with the corresponding lexeme. That's why the grammar has to be explicit in places where an identifier or a keyword can be used, e.g., 5.1.2/1 must say that *capture* can be *identifier* or *identifier* `&` or `this`, because `this` would not match the `identifier` production.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've found a specification bug - you're correct in that `this` is being captured by reference, but the text you found in §5.1.2/17 should only apply if `this` is captured by copy.

As Casey says though, it doesn't really make much sense to capture `this` by reference.

Answer (score 0):

Of course such a data member exists in the closure type.  Capture by value and capture by reference both require a data member in the closure type.  The only question is its type:

```
T /* maybe const and/or volatile */ * captured_this;
```

vs

```
T /* maybe const and/or volatile */ * const & captured_this;
```

Since `this` can't ever change, there is no observable difference between the two.

Comment: While this is "obviously" true for sane implementations, it's also explicitly not mandated by the standard.  See the quoted section of §5.1.2/15 in the question.

Comment: @rmcclellan: I *think* that the wording quoted is intended to allow storing only a single address when multiple variables captured by reference are stored adjacently.  And I would assume that optimization is allowed for `this` as well: if it can be calculated from other captured variables, it might not be separately stored.  There's no observable difference, though (unless memory is so tight that you're worried about memory consumption of the closure)

Comment: I think you're right about the intent of that wording, however, at the same time, I don't see anything in the spec that explicitly implies that interpretation.  As far as I can tell, capturing by reference isn't fully specified.  I'd like to see something in the spec that says "capturing by reference works the same way as capturing by value except the closure member is an lvalue reference".  However, I don't think such a sentence exists.

Comment: And anyway, if it did, then that rule would disallow capturing `this` by reference since `this` is a prvalue and can't initialize an lvalue reference.

Comment: @rmcclellan: You are restricted from initializing an lvalue reference with `this`.  An implementation is under no such restriction.